# Delete label and app icon in Action Bar

Tags: android, icons, android-actionbar, label

Hello I have application with action bar, style Theme.Holo.Light. But I want have only action buttons in action bar. No label with application name and icon. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override Action Bar like this: `android:actionBarStyle`.
Create your custom style (for example styles.xml) and override `android:titleTextStyle`.

Define your styles (CustomTheme and CustomActionBarStyle):

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
</style>
```

In your manifest you have to set your theme:

```
android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

This will remove the icon and the title and only display the action items.